# Ignore case for JSON-Keys in Android

Tags: android, json

i'm using in my android app native JSON-Library within Android OS. It works fine, but one thing makes me crazy.

If server interface changes and gives almost the same answer but the key notation will be a bit different (e.g. **examplekeyofmyapp** and **exampleKeyOfMyApp**) i have a problem.

Is there the way to ignore the case of the keys?

Or maybe anybody of you uses a workaround for these cases?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you had implemented your code like this
`jsonobject.get(examplekeyofmyapp)`;
then modify your code. simply change the json String to lower case.

`jsonString.toLowerCase()`. thats it, all the upper case will get converted to lower case.

Comment: i thought also about this solution, but it's not right one. because all infromations will be converted to lower case, also those, which are in values. But what if i'm not allowed to convert them?!

Comment: then the only solution ischeck it forexamplekeyofmyapp, if this key is not present then check for exampleKeyOfMyApp. check for more combinations if available.

Comment: i thought also about that. but it would make everything too complicated. But thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and the best solution I found is to check if your key has an available value.

You still have to check all the possible cases you think you could have.

```
String TAG_URL_LOWER_CASE = "url";
String TAG_URL_UPPER_CASE = "URL";

String urlValue = "";
if (!obj.isNull(TAG_URL_LOWER_CASE)) {
    urlValue = obj.getString(TAG_URL_LOWER_CASE);
} else if (!obj.isNull(TAG_URL_UPPER_CASE)) {
    urlValue = obj.getString(TAG_URL_UPPER_CASE);
}
```

You will also avoid JsonException if your key has no value associated to you key.
Hope it helps

Comment: Your case is too simple. Just imagine key newTweetsUrl (just an example). You can have NEWTWEETSURL or newtweetsUrl or if you have the crazy server implementation something like nEwtWEEtsUrL.

Comment: I know that there are several cases to manage. That's why I precised "all the possible cases you think you could have". Most of the time, there are identificated cases (full uppercase, full lowercase, first capital letter). I am opened to better solution but couldn't find it for the moment

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few years old, but I thought my solution might help others:

```
String keyName = null;
for(Iterator<String> iter = jsonData.keys(); iter.hasNext();) {
    String key = iter.next();
    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(jsonVar)) {
        keyName = key;
        break;
    }
}
jsonData.get(keyName);
```

Obviously you can change the "get()" to other types of get methods

I have core methods that I use for each of the types that handles the error for you, e.g.

```
public static String getJSONString(JSONObject jsonData, String jsonVar) {
    // start with a blank name
    String keyName = null;
    // loop through they keys to find the correct spelling
    for(Iterator<String> iter = jsonData.keys(); iter.hasNext();) {
        String key = iter.next();
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(jsonVar)) {
            keyName = key;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if the key isn't found, return a null
    if (keyName == null) {
        return keyName;
    }
    // need a try/catch around JSON stuff as the variable could be the wrong type or not exist
    try {
        return jsonData.getString(keyName);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // log the variable & the error
        Log.w("getJSONString", "failed to getJSONstring "+jsonVar+" - "+e.toString());
        // return an empty string because the "get" failed
        return "";
    }
}
```

Once you have all of the types made, it makes it easier to handle blank or missing values

I hope this helps somebody :)